# re-positioning a div on page load using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, html

hi i would like to create some animations using javascript when i thought of something which didn't work (i am a beginner in js) 
so in simple i have a box at the top of my page and i want to change its css properties on pageload like width , margin -top margin -bottom and etc

here is my code -

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div{
backgroud: #ecb4df;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
}
</style>
<script>
function codeAddress() {
            /* the code here */
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

moreover is this way correct and workable or is there any other way of tackling my problem , if yes please tell that too

Comment: `document.getElementById('div').style.marginTop = ... `?

Comment: Use css as much as possible for animations. Use javascript to add / remove / change classes of your html nodes

Answer (score 1):

I can strongly recommend you to look at CSS animations, they perform much better and are easier to maintain.

In JavaScript all you need to do is add or remove a class.

```
<style>
.my-div {
    -webkit-transition-property: top, left;
    -moz-transition-property: top, left;
    -o-transition-property: top, left;
    transition-property: top, left;
    -webkit-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
}
.initial {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>

<div id="mydiv" class="my-div initial">Ipsum Lorem</div>
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("mydiv").className = "my-div"; // remove "initial" to trigger animation
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srTnE/1/

Comment: it worked perfectly! now i can modify it as to my needs because i have a decent css knowledge , what i wanted to ask is - are there any drawbacks of using this technique over js or jquery ?

Comment: another thing , if i want to add multiple transitions like for eg - my div starts from a goes to b and after a delay goes to c please help i want this

Comment: You can still set the `top` and `left` style properties. The animation will still happen. The advantage is that you can move the div anywhere, the downside is that this is not reflected in your stylesheet which might make static templating hard since you don't know all your states.